# How to store the split value in variable to subtract from another variable in batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-delete

I have few zip files in a folder with a number in it's name with underscore like C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\xxxx_123.zip. I would like to iterate through all files and get the number in file name into a variable(fileNumber) to substract it from a another variable(buildNumber)(this is integer value which I am loading from a text file).
After first split I am able to get 123.zip(in %%a), So, for getting number from this, I split that again(got this into %%i). Then I tried assigning these values to variable fileNumber,  buildNumber and result. I checked it whether these variables are getting assigned values by writing them into a test.txt file with comma separated. but all the variable values are empty. After these values calculated properly I would like to delete the file if it satisfies the this condition if %result% GEQ %limit%.

```
set /p Build=<release_version.txt
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A result=0
for %%f in (C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\*.zip) do (
echo "fullname: %%f ">>"C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\test.txt"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ("%%f") do (
        set limit=7
        echo "FileNum: %%a">>"C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\test.txt"
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%i in ("%%a") do (
            echo "Num: %%i">>"C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\test.txt"
            set /A fileNumber=%%i
            set /A buildNumber=%Build%
            set /a result=buildNumber-fileNumber
            echo "fileNumber: %fileNumber%, buildNumber: %buildNumber%, finla: %result%">>"C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\test.txt"
            REM set /a result=%Build%-%%i
            REM echo "value is=%result%"
            REM if %result% GEQ %limit% (Del %%f)
            REM if %result% GEQ %limit% (Del "%%f")
            rem if %Build%-%%i GEQ %limit% (Del /S /Q "%%f")
        )
    )
)
```

I have been scratching my head to achieve this. So, any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Duplicate, please search before posting questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30282784/12343998) This: `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` does not do what you need it to UNLESS you expand your variables with `!` instead of `%`. Ie: !Build! !fileNumber!

Comment: You can also avoid a lot of head-aches by avoiding multi-line code blocks between parens, as you have done.  Look at `help call`, then just `...do @call ...` for each of the for loop do blocks and move all the code to subroutines.

Comment: Surely `"FileNum: 123.zip"`! , and you're pointlessly going through the pallavar of then delimiting the period in the extension to remove it. You could have eliminated it entirely by using `"%%~nf"` instead of `"%%f"`, `for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nf") do (echo "FileNum: %%a%%~xf" & echo "Num: %%a"…`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not quite have understood what you were trying to achieve, but this looks like it should work the same but more efficiently, *(and obviously uses the appropriate `!`'s for the delayed variable)*.

```batch-file
Set /P "Build=" 0< "release_version.txt"
Set "limit=7"
Set "result=0"
(
    For %%G In ("C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\*_*.zip") Do (
        Echo "fullname: %%G"
        For /F "EOL=: Tokens=2 Delims=_" %%H In ("%%~nG") Do (
            Echo "FileNum: %%H%%xG"
            Echo "Num: %%H"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            Set /A result=Build - %%H
            Echo "fileNumber: %%H, buildNumber: %Build%, final: !result!"
            Rem If !result! GEq %limit% Del /A /F "%%G"
            EndLocal
        )
    )
) 1> "C:\codedeploy\uat-prod\test.txt"
```